# Win 8 64bit: How can I see memory info from the command line?

Tags: memory, windows-8, command-line, task-manager

I need to see the memory use from command line:
I have Win 8 for 64bit and `mem` command doesn't work. Even if it would have worked I'm not sure would give the memory for the entire system.

How can I see the memory use from command line, that info that can be found in Performance tab in Task Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Powershell:

`Get-Counter '\Memory\Available MBytes'`

List of counters:

`Get-Counter -ListSet *memory* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty  Counter`

Answer (score 1):

After searching the internet I found this:

> The mem command shows information about used and free memory areas and
>   programs that are currently loaded into memory in the MS-DOS
>   subsystem.
>
> The mem command is available in MS-DOS as well as in all 32-bit
>   versions of Windows. The mem command is not available in 64-bit
>   versions of Windows.

On this website: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/tp/command-prompt-commands-p2.03.htm

A workaround is this one: `wmic os get FreePhysicalMemory`

Comment: I need the Used memory :)

Answer (score 0):

I found info in a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343190/how-to-check-available-memory-ram-via-batch-script
And modified a command for my needs:

```
syteminfo | find /i "use"
```